# Passing custom class objects using parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

How can i access custom class object in a class implementing parcelable

I have a parcelable class as folows

```
class A implements Parcelable{
      private CustomClass B;
}
```

Is it possible to use that custom class as a normal variable during **`writeToParcel()`** and **`readParcel(Parcel in)`**

PS: **I can't implement parcelable on class B as it is in Non-Android module**

Comment: If you can't make `CustomClass` implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, then you will have to manually extract its fields/values and store them as things that `Parcel` does support, and then re-create the object later. What are the exact contents of `CustomClass`?

Comment: 4 integer variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you say that `CustomClass` is made of 4 integer variables. You could therefore do something like this:

```
class A implements Parcelable {

    private CustomClass B;

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(B.getFirst());
        dest.writeInt(B.getSecond());
        dest.writeInt(B.getThird());
        dest.writeInt(B.getFourth());
    }

    private A(Parcel in) {
        B = new CustomClass();
        B.setFirst(dest.readInt());
        B.setSecond(dest.readInt());
        B.setThird(dest.readInt());
        B.setFourth(dest.readInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: What if my custom class is made up of one JSONObject as well? What can I do?

Answer (score 7):

First you need to make your `CustomClass` `parcelable` as in

```
class CustomClass implements Parcelable{
   // write logic to write and read from parcel
}
```

Then, in your class `A`

```
class A implements Parcelable{
      private CustomClass B;

       @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(B, flags); // saving object 
    }

    private A(Parcel in) {
        this.B= in.readParcelable(CustomClass.class.getClassLoader()); //retrieving from parcel
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you can't make `CustomClass` as `Parcelable`, convert class as `Json String` using google `gson` and write it to `Parcel` and while reading, read `String` and convert back to `object`

```
class A implements Parcelable{
      private CustomClass B;

       @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(new Gson().toJson(B), flags); // saving object 
    }

    private A(Parcel in) {
        this.B= new Gson().fromJson(in.readString(),CustomClass.class); //retrieving string and convert it to object and assign
    }
}
```

Comment: i custom class doesn't support android, its in separate module

Comment: thanks rajan for help nice solution but i guess i'm gonna go with @Ben solution without loading an extra library